# reference for customizing a widget in Qt?

Tags: qt, animation

I want to make a widget in Qt and customize it.for example change the background and use my own one.change the shape of the buttons and animate them and the style of starting of the page and some other things that usually are using in professional softwares.is there any reference and document to learn these works?please help me....thank you

Comment: A minute's worth of googling gives you [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227). This is for Qt 4.x though, not the latest version.

Comment: you mean doesn't work on Qt 5?i'm working with 5th version

Comment: I'm not sure, it certainly was written a few years before Qt 5 was releases.

Comment: ok...thank you at all

Comment: There are many ways to do what you're trying to do. If you want to use style sheets read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) and [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/stylesheet-reference.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Style Sheet is probably what you are looking for, check the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) and [syntax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html) . By the way, QML is considered more flexible, when it comes to GUI